# Ordercloud headstart seeding data error

Tags: sitecore-commerce, ordercloud

I am setting up OrderCloud headstart environment on my local machine following this documentation: https://github.com/ordercloud-api/headstart

While Seeding OrderCloud Data using `/seed` endpoint in postman, I am getting the below error:

```
{
    "Errors": [
        {
            "ErrorCode": "InternalServerError",
            "Message": "Unknown error has occured.",
            "Data": "Unable to resolve service for type 'Headstart.API.Commands.SupplierSync.ISupplierSyncCommand' while attempting to activate 'Headstart.API.Commands.HsSupplierCommand'."
        }
    ]
}
```

I have provided all required parameters during post call. I have referred to this template body. https://github.com/ordercloud-api/headstart/blob/development/src/Middleware/src/Headstart.Common/Assets/SeedTemplate.json

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try to inject "`.Inject<ISupplierSyncCommand>()`" in "`headstart-development\src\Middleware\src\Headstart.API\Startup.cs`" file.

[image]

It might fix this error.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue.